# Orthogonal Trajectories to the solutions of $\frac{dy}{dt} = y$

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

By using the properties of the dot product, I get as answer
$y_{ortho} = \frac{1}{C}e^{-t}$ , if  $y = Ce^{t}$ and $C \neq 0$.

If a try to use the inner product of function $\int fg$, I don't get $0$ as I would expect.

What is wrong with this answer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Graphs (trajectories) being orthogonal is an entirely separate concept from the common inner product $(f,g)=\int fg\,dx$ being equal to $0$. Those two have basically nothing to do with one another. One cares about integrals, the other about derivatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the original DE $y'=y$
,substitute  $y' \to -\dfrac 1 {y'}$:
$$-\dfrac 1 {y'}=y$$
$$y'y=-1$$
$$\int ydy=-\int dt$$
The equation of the orthogonals curves are:
$$y^2+2t=C$$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Given ODE
$$ \frac{dy}{dt}= y $$

has solutions $$ y=C_1e^t$$

Its reciprocal $$ \frac {1}{y}=e^{-t}/C_1$$

is unrelated to the discussion. (Negative reciprocal of slope does not lead to the reciprocal of the function itself).

Orthogonal trajectories to given ODE are obtained by using negative reciprocal $ y'\to \dfrac{-1}{y'}$, so

$$ \frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{-1}{y} $$
has solutions $$ y=\sqrt{C_2- 2 t}.$$